# Ajax Get call to ASP.NET MVC controller is treated as "NO ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am having a ajax call in view script. From this ajax call i am trying to get the data from controller action in same website. This is triggered as Cross **No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ problem**.

Java script code looks like

```
function displaydata(id) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    url: '@Url.Action("GetSomeData", "MyData")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "id=" + id,
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (request, error) {

    },
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
```

My MyDataController.cs looks like

```
public class MyDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetSomeData(int id)
    {  
        // converted object to json string e.g. into jsonString
        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

This is working fine on local machine but after deployment actual site does not work. I receive the error No 'Access-control-allow-origin' found in header.

My question is that I am calling same server controller from which page is served so how it becomes the candidate for CORS issue?
And how to solve it?
as a technology I have website built in *ASP.NET MVC razor view with Ajax and jquery.*

I did some more tests and found that if I deploy the WebSite in IIS in One of the VM it's working. When I deploy it to cloud Web Apps then I get the same issue.

Comment: Interesting ! When you check the view source what is the value you see for the url property  of your ajax call ?

Comment: it's the same url which i am currently but the postfix path is different as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me, although I don't do why some request from the same domain were getting blocked, just like yours.

```
if (Request.UserHostName == "127.0.0.1")
{
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

Comment: Where to add these lines. My setup is working on local machine even in one of the VM. this issue comes when I deploy to Azure cloud server

Comment: In the code where the Ajax request is received and processed.

Comment: I put it but doesn't work. Even i replaced  Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); to  Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "url"); still no luck

Comment: And without the check on IP 127.0.0.1? Still doesn't work?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe this has some helpful info. http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/08/31/how-to-enable-cors-in-the-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: Also in core             if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    
                    await next();
                });
            }

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines into your **web config** file...
 And if it doesn't work let me know

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
       <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.5" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.5" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.5" />
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Not working. Help me in resolving this i am going crazy with this.

Comment: Replace <system.webServer> tag with above  code in **webconfig** file  i have edited my answer ..Try This